# Can I use "Roslyn" in Visual Studio 2017 with .NET 4.7?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, .net-4.7

I've upgraded my project with scripting capabilities and also Microsoft.CodeAnalysis nuget and it downloaded hundred of dependent System.* packages. Before it was only Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common, CSharp, CSharp.Workspaces, etc. What is happening? Does it work in Visual Studio 2017 with .NET Framework 4.7? Or is it included in 4.7 (I didn't find it anywhere)? Should I wait?

Comment: Roslyn packages work with Visual Studio 2017.  Could you describe the problem you are seeing?

Comment: Yes. I've updated the package (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis) to 2.0 and as I've said. It downloaded ton of System.*.dll dependencies. For example System.Linq or System.Collections (and much more). These were added as a reference to my project and effectively replaced the standard System.Linq pointing to GAC. It seems that this nuget doesn't recognize .NET Framework 4.7 as a satisfying dependency or something.

Comment: The System.* nugets that are downloaded are v4.3.0.

Comment: It seem that Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common package is the one having all those dependencies (>=4.3.0) and forces them to download.

Comment: I'm looking at the dependencies of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis (2.0.0) and it is dependent on .NET Standard 1.3. According to platform table of .NET Standard, .NET Framework 4.6+ should implement it. I would expect 4.7 to do that as well. Yet, this is not somehow accepted. But if I remove all the dependencies (those additional System.* nugets) it still builds OK. So there's some problem of detecting 4.7 as a valid dependency. Either it is too new or there's some deeper problem somewhere. Is it possible?

Comment: Reccomend changing the topic to be nuget related, as this will happen for any netstandard 1.3 package. Nuget will still download all of the nuget packages that are specified as dependencies.  Nuget has no way to know that the runtime assemblies are on your machine.  At runtime, the dlls will type-forward to the versions that are installed as part of the 4.7 runtime.

Comment: It's possible that it is a general nuget related thing. But I don't know if I can do this generalization. I've experienced it only with this nuget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older versions of `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common` only had a variant for .Net 4.5, with few dependencies.

But since version 1.3.0, the package also has a .Net Standard 1.3 variant, which has many dependencies, as is usual for .Net Standard 1.x packages. When installing such package into a project targeting .Net Framework 4.7, NuGet installs all the .Net Standard dependencies. As far as I know, there is nothing wrong with that and the project should work fine.

Comment: But .NET Framework 4.7 already contains .NET Standard 1.3 (.NS). These dependencies (System.Linq) knock out some of the .NET 4.7 (system) assemblies and replace them with .NS libraries (mostly lib\net46). I want to have application in 4.7 not partially in 4.6. I wouldn't care about some obscure assemblies, but not System.Linq and System.Colllections. Moreover I might to need to distribute these with the software instead of just relying on .NET 4.7 being installed. But I guess it is an explanation. Sad, but explanation.

Comment: @SmartK8 Most of those packages don't contain any implementation for .Net 4.x. They're either just reference assemblies (with no implementation), or the implementation assemblies type forward to .Net Framework assemblies.

Comment: OK, that's a bit more reasonable I guess. But still.. I just removed those unneeded packages (I see no reason to have them). It still builds OK (IMO revealing they're not needed and there's some problem detecting .NET Standard dependencies within 4.7). It will just be pain to update, but that's not that often. Maybe they'll fix this in Nuget manager future patch.